# Could there be any risks or compatibility problems that i might face on my current asp.net projects if i update visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have my development environment as follow:-

- Windows Server 2012 R2.
- Sql server 2008 R2
- visual studio 2012 professional.
- many asp.net mvc web applications created inside visual studio.

now currently the visual studio version is `11.0.50727.1` as follow:-

[image]

recently when i open visual studio, it shows an alert that there are some updates for visual studio. so i need to know if updating my visual studio can in a way or another affect my current asp.net mvc web applications? or generally speaking updating visual studio only provides additional features, bug fixes, performance improvements,, but will not affect my current project when i am running them on the fresh version of visual studio after installing the updates ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there always *could* be.

Comment: @krillgar so what i can do with this ? currently my visual studio is raising some exceptions,and causing my CPU to reaches 100% when i run projects inside it,, since our Dev server is being patched every month ,, so maybe the visual studio became a bit out of date on the current windows server...  so i think installing the latest updates might solve these problems..

Answer (score 1):

There are no such big compatibility problems there, some times you have to just update referenced DLL version to latest one.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but which dll i need to update i did not get your point

Comment: suppose you have added DLL XYZ with version 4.0.0 then some time it need to be update as per compatible version i.e. 5.0.0

Comment: so you mean when i upgrade visual studio ,, then i open old asp.net mvc web projects inside the upgraded visual studio, this can cause the projects to get upgraded also ... i think this should not be the case!!